# Jupyter notebook 64 bits installed on a windows 64 bits machine with Oracle 11g 32 bits client

Tags: python, oracle, jupyter-notebook

I'm learning Python and am totally new to Jupyter Notebook. I've Jupyter Notebook Python 3, 64 bits installation done on a 64 bits Windows machine, via Anaconda package. The machine has already got Oracle Client 11g Home installed with other applications running.

When I launch Jupyter Notebook and run a Python script which has a Oracle SQL command, there's an error message

> "The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the
>   Driver and Application"

I can only guess it is because Jupyter Notebook is 64 bits and the Oracle installed is 32 bits. How can I get it fixed? Do I need to install a 64 bits Oracle Client? If so, will it ruin my other applications which required Oracle 32 bits? I'd prefer to stay with my 32 bits Oracle client rather than installing a 64 bits version.

Thanks,

Comment: Yes it seems most likely that this is [a 32-bit vs 64-bit issue](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpyodbc%5D+%22The+specified+DSN+contains+an+architecture+mismatch+between+the+Driver+and+Application%22). So you probably need a 64-bit Oracle client. You're worried this may affect your other applications which required Oracle 32 bits. But you should explore alternate solutions such as VirtualBox or Docker. Grab an isolated environment you can use for Python and nothing else.

Comment: The windows does not matter. The Oracle client has to be in the same architecture (i.e. 32-bit vs. 64-bit) as your Python interpreter, which seems to be 64-bit. Yes, if you install 64-bit Oracle Client then other 32-bit applications which are using Oracle will not work anymore. You can install 32-bit and 64-bit Oracle client on one machine, follow this instruction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104210/badimageformatexception-this-will-occur-when-running-in-64-bit-mode-with-the-32#24120100

Comment: Wernfried Domscheit, since I've already got Anaconda Jupyter Notebook Python 64 bit installed and working, would it be possible that I add to this installation a Python 32 bit interpreter? I see that inside Jupyter Notebook, there's an option from the drop down menu for Python interpreter.